# Header image not centered and aligned on Blogger template

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger, blogspot

What I'm trying to do is have the header image (white banner with Soliya Network blog written on it) to perfectly align with the body of the design.  At the moment, the right-side is aligned but the left side always comes short.  The banner size is 1050 x 120 pixels but the html coding looks like it is resizing to a percentage of it's actual size only.

Here's a link to template of the blog: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19701820/SoliyaBlog.xml
Here is the link for what the blog looks like now: http://soliyanetwork.blogspot.com/ncr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your id: **header-wrapper**

Can be found in your css labeled: **#header-wrapper**

You need to change it to: **padding: 10px 0px**; from **padding: 10px;** to set it back to default.